# Manytomanyfields through table data list_diplay repeating grouped data

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset, distinct-values

[screendata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zabh.png)

I have Django model manytomany through table:
`bridge_qual_id`, `bridge_uoc_id`, `sequence_id`

`bridge_qual_id` is only one record where units in the qualification are attached with sequence extra field for delivery order.

I want qualification to display only once and listing all units for it.

I tried `format_html_join` in models class method and calling in `list_display` but may be doing correct.
At the moment `admin.ModelAdmin` code is just listing table column names:

`list_display = ['bridge_qual', 'bridge_uoc', 'uoc_sequence']`

I can not do `order_by` on field in MySql in backend so tried following to change queryset but no effect.

```
@admin.register(tp_uoc_sequence, site=pg_site)
class tpuocAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(tpuocAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs.extra(where= 
         ["""bridge_uoc_id IN (
             SELECT bridge_qual_id FROM tp_uoc_sequence 
             WHERE bridge_qual_id=1) as modified group by bridge_qual_id
             ORDER BY bridge_qual_id"""
             ])
        return qs

list_display = ['bridge_qual', 'bridge_uoc', 'uoc_sequence']
```

Comment: tp_uoc_sequence is through table name.

Comment: It would be ideal to have display where Qualification as heading and all the units listed as subsection underneath

Comment: I found the solution:

Comment: I found the solution: in my model qualifications, i created function then converted models tuple into list and used mark_safe to embed format_html_join. finally passed this function into list_display.I am new and don't know how to post the picture of screen now. however, it <qual>: then each line <li>units</li>

Comment: def get_uocs_list(self):
        mylist = []
        for u in self.uoc.all():
            mylist.append(u.uoc_code)
        
        mystr = format_html_join('\n','<ul><li>{0}</li></ul>', ((i,) for i in mylist))
        return mark_safe('<div>{0}{1}</div>'.format(self.qual_code, mystr))